# Legendre symbols (p/q) = (a/q)

Tags: quadratic-reciprocity

Suppose q and p are odd primes and p = q+4a for some integer a. From the properties of the Legendre symbol and the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity prove that the following two identities hold.

(p/q) = (a/q), and (a/p) = (a/q)

---

So i first did the LAW, such that if p=q=3 (mod4) then either (p/q) = -(q/p) or (p/q) = (q/p)

with that i did some mod stuff like, p = 4a(mod q) and 4a = p (mod q)
this kind of implies that (p/q) = (a/q) right?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564839/let-p-q4a-prove-that-left-fracap-right-left-fracaq-right

Answer (score 1):

Since $p=q+4a$ we have $$ \left( \frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{4}{q}\right)\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)$$
but as $\left(\frac{4}{q}\right)=1$ ($4$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ because $4\equiv 2^2\pmod q$)
 then
$$ \left( \frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)$$

on the other hand by the reciprocity law we have
$$ \left( \frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}}\left( \frac{q}{p}\right)= (-1)^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}}\left( \frac{-1}{p}\right)\underbrace{\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)}_{=1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\underbrace{(-1)^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}}\left( \frac{-1}{p}\right)}_{=1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$$

Comment: And for the second one: $$\left(\frac ap\right)=\pm\left(\frac {q+4a}a\right)=\pm\left(\frac qa\right)=\left(\frac aq\right)$$